# Git LFS Push stuck

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

Every time when I try to push rep with lfs, I get stuck at the same file.

Here is my log:

```
$ git push -u origin --all
warning: redirecting to https://git.gamewheelstudio.ru/gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git/
Uploading LFS objects:  92% (1283/1401), 8.3 GB | 0 B/s
```

Other repos without lfs works fine

P.S. I pushed already existing rep to another server. And also renamed old rep to origin-old

I used method from gitlab that works fine for repos w/out lfs

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin linkToProject
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

And also try it with ssh and http too

Problem step is "git push -u origin --all"

UPDATE
ADD log after some commands

```
    $ GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin --all
18:14:36.467850 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/Asbjorn/AppData/Local/Fork/gitInstance/2.36.1/mingw64/bin
18:14:36.470842 git.c:459               trace: built-in: git push -u origin --all
18:14:36.471840 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-http origin http://git.gamewheelstudio.ru/gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git
18:14:36.482811 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/Asbjorn/AppData/Local/Fork/gitInstance/2.36.1/mingw64/libexec/git-core
18:14:36.484806 git.c:748               trace: exec: git-remote-http origin http://git.gamewheelstudio.ru/gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git
18:14:36.484806 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git-remote-http origin http://git.gamewheelstudio.ru/gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git
18:14:36.494778 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/Asbjorn/AppData/Local/Fork/gitInstance/2.36.1/mingw64/libexec/git-core
18:14:36.503783 http.c:689              == Info: Couldn't find host git.gamewheelstudio.ru in the (nil) file; using defaults
18:14:36.508741 http.c:689              == Info:   Trying 65.109.48.190:80...
18:14:36.527891 http.c:689              == Info: Connected to git.gamewheelstudio.ru (65.109.48.190) port 80 (#0)
18:14:36.527891 http.c:636              => Send header, 0000000218 bytes (0x000000da)
18:14:36.527891 http.c:648              => Send header: GET /gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
 :83690,"actions":{"upload":{"href":"http://git.gamewheelstudio.ru/gamewheelstudio/Atrophia.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/577a932ae33a383cdd3c927fec80c7668fa14a1f75f7edd2cdb577df77a1d1de/83690","header":{"Authorization":"Basic cm9vdDpleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlKa1lYUmhJanA3SW1GamRHOXlJam9pY205dmRDSjlMQ0pxZEdraU9pSXdOREV5TldZd05DMHpPRGxpTFRRM01USXRZVEJpTmkweU56VTBZMkUwTjJFd1lUa2lMQ0pwWVhRaU9qRTJOekkxT0RZeE56UXNJbTVpWmlJNk1UWTNNalU0TmpFMk9Td2laWGh3SWpveE5qY3lOVGt6TXpjMGZRLmZCU1FDVGFGdUJJejJmQ19wRzlMc2d4NzE4NXdpSXFxYWw4WS1FeF8tUms=","Content-Type":"application/octet-stream","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked"}}}},{"oid":"de9415aaa33d7bec00808c57238040c522774b62bbcfd754d97edd986b155a54","size":53113}]}18:16:38.567395 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern ".git" of type gitignore
18:16:38.567395 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: creating pattern "**/.git" of type gitignore
18:16:38.568525 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "tmp"
18:16:38.569071 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "3327239305"
18:16:38.569071 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "3673913061"
```

Comment: Adds log after git_trace and other from answer, but it's to massive and i pasted small part of it but can't exactly translate this infos

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes, getting the files from the server may simply be very slow and take a long time, and you just have to wait for it to finish. You do not have to accept this, but it may be all you can do or may have time for in some situations.**

**If you are unsure whether it is stuck or just slow, check the answer given down to see what the command is doing while it is "stuck".**

The way you'd go about debugging this is to set `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` in the environment when performing your Git operation.
(If you're using Git Bash, you can just prepend those, space-separated, to the git clone command.).

That will let you see if Git LFS is actually starting up and making progress. If so, you'll be able to see the requests being made and if there's a problem with them.

If it's not, then things are trickier. We have seen some cases where people using a non-default antivirus can see breakage because Git LFS is written in Go, and Go binaries tend to have unconventional structures. Its possible endpoint monitoring software on Windows could do the same thing. In either case, you should remove the affected software, reboot, and use just the default antivirus instead.

Comment: I waited around 4 hours but nothing changed, already try git_trace and other commands but i can't translate it correctly (add log to question undre update)

Comment: i think you have to uninstall and install again and try again